# Есть ли какие-нибудь классы\методы, чтобы изменять URL-путь в браузере не вручную, а программно?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Например, изначально URL-путь был таким http://localhost:xxxx/, потом я его поменял вручную на http://localhost:xxxx/home и сработала кое-какая логика. Но я хочу, чтобы я не вручную изменял URL-путь, а за меня это делал какой-нибудь класс\метод, который может изменять и обращаться к пути. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что-нибудь, а то в инете найти не могу, потому что с "техническим языком" всё плохо.

Comment: Это называется редирект/переадресация, первая ссылка гугла - [тык](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/5.5.php).

Comment: JavaScript `window.location`

Answer (score 0):

Денис Бредун. Если я правильно понял вас, то редирект с сервера не поможет. Человек открыл страницу, а затем ему нужно перейти куда-то. По сути это другая страница и чтоб перейти туда нужна либо готовая ссылка, на которую нужно нажать,перейти либо отложенный вызов, редирект из браузера.