# Как изменить https://localhost:xxxxx на https://localhost:xxxxx/login?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Как изменить https://localhost:xxxxx на https://localhost:xxxxx/login ? Чтобы уже в начале работы приложения url-адрес был https://localhost:xxxxx/login?

Comment: Если пользователь неавторизован, или всегда? Не лучше ли если пользователь сам нажмет "войти"? Дополните вопрос.

Comment: Браузер получает ту страницу которую запрашивает. Если вам нужна переадресация на другую страницу, то [в предыдущем вашем вопросе вам ответили](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1164069/177631).

Comment: Используйте Cookie с шифрованными данными, а при проверке пусть сам решает какую страницу открывать.

Answer (score 1):

Если Вам требуется, что открылась изначально любая другая страница, но не главная, можете изменить маршрут: [почитать документацию о маршрутах](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Пример файл startup.cs:

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Login}/{id?}");
        });
```

Controller - относится к контроллеру.

Action - к методу, который вызывается.

Если, Вам нужно **переадресация**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
 public IActionResult Login()
    {
        return Redirect("~/Home/Privacy");
    }
```

Я отправляю человека на другую страницу при попытке обратиться к Login.

Почитать о переадресации: [тык](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/5.5.php)